# Making a Caesar Cipher in Java

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am making a Caesar cipher for my intro to computer science class and I am stuck. I already figured out how to satisfy some of the required elements for the project like spaces and I had it working when the encryption key was set at a fixed number. However, one of the requirements is that the alphabet wraps around when you hit "z" and that the user can input their own encryption key value. Also it needs to encrypt and decrypt messages.
Any tips anyone could give me as to where I am going wrong would be appreciated!
Here is what I have so far: (I was making this in Eclipse)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaesarCipher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the message? (all lowercase)");
        String plainText = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the encryption key: ");
        int encryptionKey = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The encrypted text is: ");
        int charPos = 0;

        while (charPos < plainText.length()) {
            char currChar = plainText.charAt(charPos);
            int charAsNum = (int) currChar;
            int cipherLetterAsNum = charAsNum + encryptionKey;
            char cipherLetter = (char) cipherLetterAsNum;

            if (currChar == 'x' || currChar == 'y' || currChar == 'z') {
                currChar = plainText.charAt(charPos);
                charAsNum = (int) currChar;
                cipherLetterAsNum = charAsNum + encryptionKey - 26;
                cipherLetter = (char) cipherLetterAsNum;
                System.out.print(cipherLetter);
                charPos = charPos + 1;
            }

            if (currChar == ' ') {
                System.out.print(currChar);
            } else {
                System.out.print(cipherLetter);
            }
            charPos = charPos + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a) Use the input char to decide whether it needs to be changed. b) The `<` operator to decide, if you need to substract 26. Alternatively you could use the `%` operator: `cOut = (cIn - 'a' + encryptionKey) % 26 + 'a'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check whether the encryptedChar is greater than 91 (the ascii value of z), and if it is, it should substract 26. If you want to decrypt a text, you just have to substract the encryptionKey and if the encryptedChar is smaller than  65 (ascii value of a), you have to add 26. I'm not sure whether the ascii values are correct, so better look it up.